# I cannot display an image by binding an ImageSource property to an Image control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` with a Label inside the `DataTemplate`. Each time the element displayed inside the `CarouselView` is changed, the ImageSource property of an Image control located outside the `CarouselView` is updated

The `CarouselView` gets the content from a List

```
List<FraseClass> ListaFrasi = new List<FraseClass>

public class FraseClass : ViewModelBase
{
     private ImageSource _ImgSource;

     public ImageSource ImgSource
     {
         get { return _ImgSource; }
         set
         {
            _ImgSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImgSource");
         }
     }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ff:CachedImage  x:Name="ImgFrase" Scale="2" FadeAnimationEnabled="True" DownsampleToViewSize="True" />
```

**c#:**

```
private void CurrentItemChanged (object sender, CurrentItemChangedItemArgs e)
{
    if (ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource == null)
    {
         string LinkImg = "ftp://epiz_27426656@ftpupload.net/htdocs/ImgSfondo/" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Index).DayOfYear + ".jpg";
         byte[] ImgByte = WebLcient.DownloadData(LinkImg);
         MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(ImgByte);
         ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mStream);
         ImgFrase.Source= ImageSource.FromStream(() => mStream);
    }
     else
    {
         ImgFrase.Source = ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource;
    }
}
```

If the object inside the list does not have a value inside a property, download the image and the code works perfectly, if instead that object already has data inside the property, I try to display the image, but in reality the same image continues to be displayed

Comment: try changing to a regular Image control.  You are using CachedImage but since you are loading from stream I don't think it has a key to use for the cache.  Or try saving the downloaded image locally and use the path instead of creating the ImageSource from stream

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `List<FraseClass>` to cache the pictures, and ImgFrase refers to the different picture depends on the index of `List<FraseClass>`. But you find out the picture will not change while you change the Label inside the `CarouselView`. Is that right?

Your description of **code works perfectly** and **the same image continues to be displayed** is not clear enough. But still, you can focus on:

1. Whether the `ListaFrasi` cache the right pictures.
2. Whether the event was triggered when you change the label in the
    `CarouselView`.

I am a little confused about this code:

```
ImgFrase.Source= ImageSource.FromStream(() => mStream);
```

Why you not just directly take this?

```
if (ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource == null)
{
     string LinkImg = "ftp://epiz_27426656@ftpupload.net/htdocs/ImgSfondo/" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Index).DayOfYear + ".jpg";
     byte[] ImgByte = WebLcient.DownloadData(LinkImg);
     MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(ImgByte);
     ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mStream);
}

ImgFrase.Source = ListaFrasi[Index].ImgSource;
```

If I am right, the memory stream couldn't be used twice.

And if you still could not solve the problem, could you provide the complete code?